# Should the [pyo] tag be renamed?

Tags: discussion, tags

I created the [pyo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyo) tag today for the [Python pyo audio library](https://github.com/belangeo/pyo) and spent some time tagging every relevant question (~13) with it.

After I was done, it dawned on me that a user might see this tag and not be able to distinguish the pyo library from the Python `.pyo` file; for example, if you search for "pyo" on Stack Overflow most of the questions are related to `.pyo` files.

It also occurred to me that because there were only 13 questions, maybe a tag wasn't necessary at this time.

Perhaps it should be renamed to [pyo-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyo-library) or be removed.